# ReactJS Javascript - Dynamic Add / Remove Rows of Input in Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

I am currently working on a web app that requires a dynamic form to be generated, where I can press an 'add' or 'remove' button to add or remove instances of a model in the form. For example, the structure of the form is like this:

Company Name: ...
Address: ...
Telephone Number: ...

(below is the part where i need to dynamically add and remove instances since there can be multiple POCs from 1 company)

POC1 Name:  ...
POC1 Email: ...
POC1 Phone Number: ...

POC2 Name:  ...
POC2 Email: ...
POC2 Phone Number: ...

etc.

I came across this example of how to do it (https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-lichterman-br63z?file=/index.js) , but I can't seem to understand some parts of the code. I am new to Javascript and I am using ReactJS as the front end of my app. Below is the snippet of the code

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Form, Input, Button, Col, Row } from "antd";
import { MinusCircleOutlined, PlusOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const rules = [{ required: true }];

const DynamicFieldSet = () => {
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log("Received values of form:", values);
  };

   return (
     <Form onFinish={onFinish} className="my-form">
      <Form.List name="users">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          /**
           * `fields` internal fill with `name`, `key`, `fieldKey` props.
           * You can extends this into sub field to support multiple dynamic fields.
           */
          return (
            <div>
              {fields.map((field, index) => (
                <Row key={field.key}>
                  <Col>
                    <Form.Item
                      name={[field.name, "lastName"]}
                      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "lastName"]}
                      rules={rules}
                    >
                      <Input placeholder="last name" />
                    </Form.Item>
                  </Col>
                  <Col>
                    <Form.Item
                      name={[field.name, "firstName"]}
                      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "firstName"]}
                      rules={rules}
                    >
                      <Input placeholder="first name" />
                    </Form.Item>
                  </Col>
                  <Col flex="none">
                    <MinusCircleOutlined
                      className="dynamic-delete-button"
                      onClick={() => {
                        remove(field.name);
                      }}
                    />
                  </Col>
                </Row>
               ))}
              <Form.Item>
                 <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  }}
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add field
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>

      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
      );
    };

ReactDOM.render(<DynamicFieldSet />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

I do not really understand where the 'fields' variable came from, and also where the 'index' variable came from. Also, how is the arrow function being executed without any explicit call for that function? Any help is appreciated and in the mean time I will continue looking through and trying to understand arrow functions as much as possible as I am still new to it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The example you posted uses the npm package `antd` which is a React UI Library. It uses `FormList` (provided by `antd`) to provide the functionality that you are looking to achieve. You can check out the code of the component that is used here https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/form/FormList.tsx.

The arrow function that is passed to the `FormList` is called a "render prop", it is passed to the `FormList` via the `children`-prop and executed from there, that's why it does not actually get called in the example code. You can read up on the concept here https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html, it is a little hard to get at first but will make sense after a while.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, i will go and check out the component FormList, and familiarise myself with the render prop. i am still new to javascript and reactjs, and so i really appreciate the help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

So `.map()` is a method you can call on an array which returns a new array. You pass a function to the `.map()` method and you can name some input params to be used internally in your map function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

When the function runs the map function fills in the gaps. By this what I mean is that `fields` and `index` can take any name you wish. You could call them `f` and `i` and you will see examples of this in peoples code.

Basically your function then uses these names internally as they are passed down from map when the function is executed, the function runs for each item in the array.

So in a basic example, you loop over the array and each time you loop you pass the function the current array item and the index count. Here is a simple example of an array with a `.map()` returning a new array of objects.

```js
const result = [1, 2, 3].map((number, i) => {
  return {
    number: number,
    index: i,
  }
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: okay i think i understand the basic usage of the map function thanks to u, thank you for your answer and clarification, and sorry for the amateur questions haha i am still new to javascript :-)

Comment: @jason your welcome! I have always found sometimes people explain very simple ideas in a very wordy or technical manner which can make understanding something simple actually quite difficult. :-)